# Backbone How-to Repeating Sub View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller

Ok, I have one main view, of which I load multiple subviews. Of which one particular subview is repeated intentionally. This subview is a Unordered List, each list item is its own model (or should be), and in that each one of these duplicated subviews has its own set of events.

However it seems I've coded myself into a corner currently as what I've done makes it seem that the last subview appended to the views is the only one the DOM is paying mind to, the other ones no longer appear bound.

Here is the most relevant code to my plight.

```
var myApp = myApp || {Models:{}, Collections:{}, Views:{}, Activated:{}}
(function () {
    'use strict';
    myApp.Views.PortForwardView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.__wrapper',
        initialize: function () {
            this.render();
            this.model = new listItem();
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderItem);
            return this;
        },

        // loading the primary DOM containers
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(z.fromTemplate('main-list'));
            return this;
        },

        // Render a lone row to the DOM
        renderItem: function (data) {
            var subView = new myApp.Views.SubListItemView();
            data = data.toJSON();
            this.$el.find('.__existing').append(subView.render(data));
            return this;
        },

    });

    myApp.Views.SubListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.__existing',
        events: {
            'click .__update' : 'updateRule'
        },

        render: function (data) {
            $('.__existing__empty').remove();
            return z.fromTemplate('main-list-row', data);
        },

        updateRule: function (event) {
            var $elem = $(event.currentTarget);
            console.log($elem.closest('form').find('input#id').val())
        }

    });
})();
```

Comment: It looks like your pointing all your sub-views at the same DOM element (`.__existing`), what you probably want to do is instead of declaring your `el` in your subview declare the `className` and then append its view to your container (`subView.render(data).el`).

Answer (score 0):

@Jack comment points into the right direction. As this is a quite common pattern to reuse views my suggested solution is to leverage a tool like [BackboneLayoutManager](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/wiki/Nested-views). This way you don't specify the `el` but typically the `classname` or `id`. Then you use functions like `insertView` to reuse and hook the same view into different jQuery selectors used as placeholders within the parent view template

```
myApp.Views.PortForwardView.setView("subViewHolder1", new myApp.Views.SubListItemView());

myApp.Views.PortForwardView.setView("subViewHolder2", new myApp.Views.SubListItemView());
```

A quick [screencast](https://vimeo.com/32765088)